# Como mudar a cor da StatusBar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

Como mudo a cor desta parte da app?
Queria por tudo da mesma cor verde como esta mais em baixo. [image: A parte que esta rodeada de vermelho]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só editar o seu arquivo `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/suaCor</item>
</style>
```

dependendo das permissões da API é possível utilizar o [setStatusBarColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int))

[Aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) tem um tutorial do Google sobre paleta de cores

Answer (score 5):

A cor da StatusBar é por padrão a cor atribuída a `colorPrimaryDark`.
Em versões inferiores à 21 só é possível alterá-la alterando a `colorPrimaryDark`. Que implica que todos os componentes que usem essa cor a tenham também alterada.

Em versões iguais ou superiores é possível fazê-lo no style da aplicação recorrendo a `android:statusBarColor`

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

ou, via código

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
```